What are the venting requirements for a roof deck when insulating below?
I'm wondering how to know what is sufficient venting, and if someone has other ideas to DIY a space for storage in a vented, unconditioned, attic (without a ridge vent).
I have a vented attic (with soffit and gable vents). I want to take about 6-feet on either side of the ridge and make a bit of a storage space that doesn't get too hot (attic gets up to ~110-115). I'm wondering how I can insulate along the roof, while stay keeping an adequately vented roof.
My roof is 2x4 rafters at 24" on center, the decking is 1x slats and plywood overtop of them with asphalt shingles. My climate is mild (northern California coast), no snow chance.
I'm guessing that if I opened up the ends  of the slats, that would not be enough venting.
I was thinking then, to put rafter vents up and insulate on the other side of them. However, anyone that I've seen do something like this, has a ridge vent at the top, and my assembly does not. Also, about every 4th soffit has a vent (though I could change that).

Are you sure you even need venting to begin with? Given that you are in a place that doesn't get significant snow, going to an unvented roof may be your best bet here...

Possibly not. If I seal my soffit and gable vents, then it seems I need a dehumidifier or a vapor diffusion port with some air circulation?
(attic is small, 5/12 pitch over a 28' wide structure)

If you're going to insulate the roof, don't bother venting it (in your situation)
Given that you are in a place that does not see significant snow, you're probably better off converting your roof to an unvented roof assembly outright and conditioning the resulting attic than trying to deal with having storage in a vented attic.  See BSI-119 for the gory details, but for here, note that you'll probably either need to use spray foam, or retrofit some insulation atop the roof deck, in order to control moisture adequately.
You'll also need to make sure that you don't have any combustion equipment in your attic that isn't capable of, and set up for, sealed combustion, but non-sealed-combustion gas appliances are pretty obsolete by now, and ditching gas in a mild climate like yours may be for the best in any case.

Retrofitting insulation atop the roofdeck seems like a lot of effort (I'd have to take off and re-install all my shingles?)
Full spray foam would be an option, but I'm wondering if there's something that's lower effort.
I read through that article and CRC R806.5. It seems like there might be an easier option where I install a vapor diffusion port and use air permeable insulation between the rafters. Seems there's some kind of airflow constraint I'll need to meet in 5.2.10 though.

@ChrisT check your climate zone.  vapor diffusion might be an option for you, but it also very well may not be.

Yeah, CRC R806.5 item 5.2 says zones 3-15, and I'm 3.
Seems like I could do a vapor diffusion port and air-permeable insulation between the rafters and then circulate some air there. Perhaps batts and a reflective barrier would be sufficient then. Does that sound correct?

@ChrisT I wouldn't use the reflective barrier, but if you can do vapor diffusion + air permeable insulation, that might be the most practical thing in your circumstance
